# (C++) Finding end() for an iterator when only the iterator is available?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Assuming code that looks vaguely like this:

```
bool LoadGame() {
  vector<string> SaveFile = LoadFromSaveFile();
  Data = SaveFile.begin();
  LoadCharacters(&Data);
    // containing LoadOneCharacter(&Data) calls
  LoadLocations(&Data);
    // >> LoadOneLocation(&Data) calls
  // etc.
}
```

Is there any way to check whether Data is currently pointing at SaveFile::end() while within LoadCharacters(), LoadLocations(), etc., without passing SaveFile::end() to all the functions invoked by LoadGame()?

(If only dereferencing end() and beyond threw an exception instead of generating undefined behavior!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible, in the general case

In specific cases, you may be able to exploit implementation specific details of the iterator implementation to get at the container.

The iterators of the standard container library have no such details *documented* AFAIR.

---

A special case would be input iterators like `std::istream_iterator<>` which can always be compared to *default-constructed* instance of itself to check for end-of-input.

```
std::istringstream iss("test");
std::istream_iterator<char> it(iss);

// you can always check for end of input:
while (std::istream_iterator<char>() != it)
{
    it++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I'll play it safe for now.

Comment: @ExOttoyuhr A sound strategy. Note that it is not about playing safe, it is about sticking to the documented behaviour of the libraries _only_. The rest is not just not safe, it is just not supported, might break depending on build configurations, library versions and so on. Just not an option, really (**unless you control the iterator implementation yourself**)

Comment: That's what I mean by "playing it safe." :) Just because an undefined behavior produced by a certain version of a particular compiler, on a particular OS, might be desirable, doesn't mean that using the behavior is a good idea. (As for personal implementations of standards, not having to worry about personal implementations is what standards are _for_.) (And looking at my original comment, I really regret saying "for now;" it makes it sound like I'll head off into C++ Dodge City the moment it suits my fancy...)

Comment: Pedantry Ahead: Undefined behaviour is really never desired. Implementation-defined Behaviour != Undefined Behaviour. In this case, _undocumented_ behaviour is still implementation defined, but supported for external use... (Yeah. It's a wild word web.) Cheers :)

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible in general. In many implementations many kinds of iterators are just pointers, and have no understanding of the underlying container.

You'll need to pass both iterators, or pass a different structure such as a `range` ( which is in `boost` but not C++0x IIRC).

Comment: Thanks -- especially for the point on iterators just being pointers under the hood, which I hadn't suspected.

Comment: @ExOttoyuhr : Not just "under the hood" – all non-void pointers are also valid random access iterators.